# Многопоточная обработка большого кол-ва файлов

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Необходимо написать небольшое приложение, которое будет обрабатывать огромное кол-во файлов (40-50 тысяч)

Для улучшения производительности нужна многопоточность, но как она должна быть реализована? 40 тысяч потоков - плохой вариант.

Comment: используйте пул потоков

Comment: Общее правило - потоков должно быть не больше, чем ядер/процессоров - это раз (иначе переключение съест всю выгоду... исключение - когда потоки часто чего-то ожидают), а второе - если все потоки будут активно работать с диском, боюсь, выгоды от многопоточности может не оказаться вовсе - каждый поток будет дергать диск в своем направлении. Ответ, по сути, один - эксперимент, профилирование.

Comment: @Harry выходит, что нужно использовать 2-4 потока, которые после обработки одного файла, будут запрашивать путь к следеющему?

Comment: кол-во потоков может сильно зависеть от текущего железа. К примеру ssd или hdd. Поэтому, как написали выше - только экспериментировать с кол-вом потоков и замерять скорость. Да, создать 40к потоков достаточно накладно (на 32битных системах Вы скорее всего упретесь где то в 600-700 потоков, больше ось просто не позволит).

Comment: Проблема в том, где именно находятся файлы - на одном диске, на разных... как к ним выполняется обращение. Если ресурс один, вычислительная часть быстрая - то не думаю, что будет большая выгода: большую часть времени будет ожидать завершения дисковой операции. Я не слишком хорошо разбираюсь в железе, чтобы говорить что-то уверенно, но обычные простенькие диски, с которыми мне приходилось иметь дело, крайне плохо реагируют, когда к ним одновременно лезут несколько задач/программ. Ощущение, что при переключении у диска сбрасываются кеши или что-то вроде... Так что - наращивайте потоки и смотрите

Comment: В начале будет указана папка и в ней будут все 40к файлов. думаю начать с 2х потоков

Comment: В современных ОС кэширование дисковых данных может существенно уменьшить время работы программы при повторном запуске. Таким образом, эффект от собственно распараллеливания будет виден при втором и последующих запусках, а при первом вызове программы диск скорее всего замаскирует прибавку скорости. В любом случае, проводите самостоятельные эксперименты на конкретной системе. Определитесь с технологией, которую собираетесь использовать - POSIX Threads, Qt или Boost, OpenMP / TBB и иже с ними, иные средства, свойственные языкам, отличным от C++.

Answer (score 0):

Общее правило - потоков должно быть не больше, чем ядер/процессоров - это раз (иначе переключение съест всю выгоду... исключение - когда потоки часто чего-то ожидают), а второе - если все потоки будут активно работать с диском, боюсь, выгоды от многопоточности может не оказаться вовсе - каждый поток будет дергать диск в своем направлении. Ответ, по сути, один - эксперимент, профилирование.